# How do you install Swift package binaries after building them?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

After building a package how do you install it on the system?

For example, I'm trying to install [Swift language server](https://github.com/RLovelett/langserver-swift) but I have no idea what to do after `swift build`. Do I have to copy executables and libraries manually?

In CMake/make world there is always a `make install` step. Is there anything similar in Swift package manager? There doesn't seem to be an `install` command or something similar. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift Package Manager produces plain executables, in `.build/debug` or `.build/release` directory. You can see the last line in its output `Linking .build/debug/<the name of the main module in the Package>`.

If not specified otherwise, you can just run the result executable, as any other executable, by typing its path in the command line and providing parameters as needed.

Swift Package Manager does not support custom scripts or targets, like `install`, `deploy` etc. If there is a need for installation/deployment automation, it should be done by additional scripts or tools, like Makefile.